# Create a ggplot with percentages

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I'd like to make a ggplot  (line plot) that displays the percentage of values (A, B, C, D) per time step on the x axis (y axis). When I melt my data frame, I only have two columns; how can I calculate the percentage?

Data structure:

[image: Data structure]

Sample data:

```
structure(list(`09:20` = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "D"), 
    `09:30` = c("B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "C", "C"), `09:40` = c("C", 
    "C", "C", "B", "B", "D", "D"), `09:50` = c("A", "A", "A", 
    "D", "D", "D", "D")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(`09:20` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), `09:30` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), `09:40` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), `09:50` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reshaping to long format use e.g. `group_by` + `summarise` to compute the count per time and value, then compute the percentages by time and plot:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

d1 <- d %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "time", values_to = "value") %>% 
  group_by(time, value) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>%  
  mutate(pct = n / sum(n)) %>% 
  ungroup()
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'time'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.

ggplot(d1, aes(time, pct, color = value, group = value)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

[image]